# Partitioning a String into more pieces with separating char in Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell

I have the following homework:

> Define a function split :: Char -> String -> [String] that splits a string, which consists of substrings separated by a separator, into a list of strings.

```
Examples:

split '#' "foo##goo" = ["foo","","goo"]    
split '#' "#" = ["",""]
```

I have written the following function:

```
split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split c "" = [""]
split a "a" = ["",""]
split c st =  takeWhile (/=c) st : split c tail((dropWhile (/=c) st))
```

It does not compile, and I can't see why.
TakeWhile adds all the characters which are not c to the result, then tail drops that c that was found already, and we recursively apply split to the rest of the string, gotten with dropWhile. The : should make a list of "lists" as strings are lists of chars in Haskell. Where is the gap in my thinking?

Update:

I have updated my program to the following:

```
my_tail :: [a]->[a]
my_tail [] = []
my_tail xs = tail xs

split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split c "" = [""]
split a "a" = ["",""]
split c st =  takeWhile (/=c) st ++ split c (my_tail(dropWhile (/=c) st))
```

I still get an error, the following:
[image]

Why is the expected type [String] and then [Char]?

Comment: can you explain to me what `split a "a" = ["",""]` is doing here? Why do you split `"a"` into `["",""]`?

Comment: Well a is the split character, so it splits "a" into what's before and after a, so "nothing"

Comment: but (a) I do not understand why you consider splitting with `'a'` a special case, and (b) then shouldn't you use single quotes? like `split 'a' "a" = ...`.?

Comment: to be honest, the base case was given. now that you say it like that, it seems weird to me also..

Comment: `a` in that case is the *name* bound to the split character; `split a [c] | a == c = ["", ""]`

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of error messages. Instead, copy and paste them.

Comment: why's that? @dfeuer

Comment: Accessibility, primarily: not everyone can see images. They also defeat search engines, making it hard for people to find questions relevant to the problems they're facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this does not compile is because Haskell, sees your last clause as:

```
split c st = takeWhile (/=c) st : split c tail ((dropWhile (/=c) st))
```

It thus thinks that you apply *three* parameters to `split`: `c`, `tail` and `((dropWhile (/=c) st))`. You should use brackets here, like:

```
split c st = takeWhile (/=c) st : split c (tail (dropWhile (/=c) st))
```

But that will not fully fix the problem. For example if we try to run your testcase, we see:

```
Prelude> split '#' "foo##goo"
["foo","","goo"*** Exception: Prelude.tail: empty list
```

[**`tail :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:tail) is a "non-total" function. For the empty list, `tail` will error. Indeed:

```
Prelude> tail []
*** Exception: Prelude.tail: empty list
```

Eventually, the list will run out of characters, and then `tail` will raise an error. We might want to use [**`span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span) here, and use pattern matching to determine if there is still some element that needs to be processed, like:

```
split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split _ [] = [[]]
split c txt = pf : rst
    where rst | (_:sf1) <- sf = split c sf1
              | otherwise = []
          (pf,sf) = span (c /=) txt
```

Here `span (c /=) txt` will thus split the non-empty list `txt` in two parts `pf` (*prefix*) is the longest prefix of items that are *not* equal to `c`. `sf` (suffix) are the remaining elements.

Regardless whether `sf` is empty or not, we emit the prefix `pf`. Then we inspect the suffix. We know that either `sf` is empty (we reached the end of the list), or that the the first element of `sf` is equal to `c`. We thus use *pattern guard* to check if this matches with the `(_:sf1)` pattern. This happens if `sf` is non-empty. In that case we bind `sf1` with the tail of `sf`, and we recurse on the tail. In case `sf1` is empty, we can stop, and thus return `[]`.

For example:

```
Prelude> split '#' "foo##goo"
["foo","","goo"]
Prelude> split '#' "#"
["",""]
```

Comment: what is are pf,sf1,sf in your code? I'm new to haskell and I don't understand the code that well

Comment: @SavannahGemp: `pf` is here the `takeWhile (/c) txt` (prefix), whereas `sf` is the `dropWhile (/c) txt` (suffix), `sf1` is the tail of the suffix, given that tail exists.

Comment: would it maybe also work if i wrote a my_tail function that goes like my_tail [] = [], my_tail xs = tail xs ?

Comment: Also, do you have a link or sth with a good explaination of pattern matching?

Comment: @SavannahGemp: see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching